# Importing a CSV with many records - updating many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with about 100K item numbers :

`id`, `itemnumber`,`text`,`orignal_qty`,`counted_qty`

Im now importing a CSV file with maybe 100K records :

`itemnumber_in`,`qty`

That contains a count of the actual stock - i then need now to update the "counted_qty" in the main database for each record in the CSV.

How would i go about that ? would i read each line in the file from start to finish and do a :

```
UPDATE maintable SET counted_qty = counted_qty + qty WHERE itemnumber_in = itemnumber
```

Or is there a smarter/faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the CSV file using `LOAD DATA` and then use a join to update `itemnumbers`:

```
UPDATE itemnumbers a INNER JOIN import b
    ON a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber_in
SET a.counted_qty = a.counted_qty + b.qty
```

The nice thing about this approach is a record in `itemnumbers` will only be updated in the event that it matched something in the input CSV file.

**Update:**

If you first want to aggregate your imported data by id number, then you can use a subquery in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE itemnumbers a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT itemnumber_in, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM import
    GROUP BY itemnumber_in
) b
    ON a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber_in
SET a.counted_qty = a.counted_qty + b.qty
```

Comment: thank alot - will this also work in case there are many instances of the same itemnumber in the CSV file ( which there will ) ?

Comment: So are you saying the same id may appear more than once in the import?  If so then do you want to aggregate the qty field?

Comment: yes, ex they can have 50 qty for itemnumber 11223344 - but it can be 50  records with a qty of 1 in the CSV file.

Comment: @thorway I updated my answer with an approach I think can work if you want to first aggregate your import data.